# How to append items into new different lists while looping?

Tags: python, list, loops, facebook-graph-api, dictionary

I'm working with the Facebook Graph API and want to collect from a public facebook page all the posts and all the comments of these posts.

I already wrote a code that retrieves all the comments of 1 post, but now I want all the comments in a list of all the posts. However, I don't want them in the same list, but I want a different list per post.. or at least something that the comments are separated per post (I was also thinking of a dict with 1 key(the post) and multiple values (the comments)..)

How should I do that? The code I wrote to get the comments of 1 post is:

```
commentsperpost=[]
while True:
    i = 0
    try:
       commentsperpost+=[textpost(post=comment) for comment in comments3['data']]
       i += 1
       print(comments3['paging']['next'], i)       
       comments3 = requests.get(comments3['paging']['next']).json()
    except KeyError:
       break
```

at first I thought to make a loop but than it got all the comments into the same list..

Comment: in the first iteration of your loop you are using comments3 before assigning it

Comment: Oh I forgot to paste that, I did assigned it and this code is already working, but only for 1 post. So I only showed it that you could see where I need to work with. Do you know how I can solve my problem for the different lists while looping?

Comment: This looks like a job for the wonderful [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). Look into this, I would suggest having your keys as something to identify each post, and creating a list for each key.

Comment: But how do I then loop over my original code and put all the comments into a new list?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
commentsperpost+=[textpost(post=comment) for comment in comments3['data']]
```

you should have:

```
commentsperpost.append([textpost(post=comment) for comment in comments3['data']])
```

Comment: So this way there will be created new lists everytime I loop over the code?

Comment: For every iteration of your while loop adifferent list of comments will be added to the commentsperpost list (commentsperpost will be a list of lists), I also agree that having commentsperpost being a dictionary would be nicer since then you could access each list of comments by keyword.

Comment: Thank you! Definitely going to try that. If I want to make it a dict, do I need to make first an empty dict: commentsperpost = {} and than just keep the same code?

Comment: You would need to replace commentsperpost = [] with commentsperpost = dict()   (commentsperpost = {} actually creates an empty set), and them replace commentsperpost.append([textpost(post=comment) for comment in comments3['data']]) with commentsperpost[i]=[textpost(post=comment) for comment in comments3['data']].

Comment: Thank you! I made it work :D But now when I am retrieving the comments, at some point it says: ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'))